# Changing app install location permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

Suppose my app permits installs to external storage: `android:installLocation="auto”`.

Assume some of the users have installed the app to e.g. SD card.

For various reasons, in the next update, I want to enforce my app to be installable to internal storage only by updating the permission tag to 
`android:installLocation="internalOnly”`.

What would happen to the users with the app installed on external storage after the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will change, only new users will have that applied to them.